# How to do something after an event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, promise, fadein

I want to play an animation when another animation is done.

I used this code:

```
$("#test_01").stop().animate({height: '500'}, 2500).promise($("#test_02").fadeIn(2500));
```

This animates the two at the same time - that isn't what I want. 
I need `$("#test_01")` to work first, and after that `$("#test_02")` needs to be run.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `done` with your code:

```
$("#test_01").stop().animate(
    {height: '500'},
    2500
).promise().done(
    function(){
        $("#test_02").fadeIn(2500)
    }
);
```

The `done` function callback will work after all the code from animation has completed.

Comment: happy to help mark my answer verified so it could be helpful to others too

Answer (score 2):

Just use the complete callback of [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$("#test_01").stop().animate({
    height: '500'
}, 2500, function () {
    $("#test_02").fadeIn(2500)
});
```

If you are looking at promise based solution, then you need to get the promise object and then add a done callback to the promise where you will do the delayed operation